# Hiding divs between two ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html structure:

```
<div id='articles'>
   <div id='unread'>Unread articles</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
   <div id='read'>Read articles</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

I've created simple buttons to toggle on/off the articles based on whether the user wants to see the read/unread.

```
<div onclick='$("#read").hide();$("#unread").show();'>Show read</div>
<div onclick='$("#unread").hide();$("#read").show();'>Show unread</div>
```

What is the missing piece in the onclick event that can select the divs between the two flags ids?

I cannot put the closing tag after the last article from a certain category, I can only have it as a flag.

Comment: what is the problem in this??

Comment: @Travesty3 the reason is that I'm generating the list with a foreach loop in which I have a sorting mechanism that can only create flags between the different categories. I don't want to have two foreach loops so I can comply with the DRY principle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#unread").nextUntil("#read");
```

[This](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) returns a list of all elements in between.

Comment: and to select only divs, you can specify:
 `$("#unread").nextUntil("#read", "div");`

Answer (score 2):

Selecting all the elements between two other elements is kinda a weird thing to do.

I would suggest fixing your HTML structure to look something more like this:

```
<div id="articles">
    <h1>Unread articles</h1>
    <div id="unread">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <h1>Read articles</h1>
    <div id="read">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your buttons will work as-is. However it's not a good idea to add these events inline. It would be better to bind the onclick event in a separate JS code block. This will make it easier to maintain.

Comment: I'm aware of this, and this is how I usually approach the situation but in this case due to the following php sorting mechanism inside a foreach loop I'm able to just add flags. `<?if ($group_date !== substr($row["read"], 0, 1)) {
                    $group_date = substr($row["read"], 0, 1);
                    echo "<div class='clear'></div><div class=''></div><?=$row["read"];?><div class='clear'></div>";
                }?>`

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this could be to add a class to child divs which you want to show hide with flags like:

```
<div id='articles'>
   <div id='unread'>Unread articles</div>
    <div class="unreadChild"></div>
    <div class="unreadChild"></div>
   <div id='read'>Read articles</div>
    <div class="readChild"></div>
    <div class="readChild"></div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
<div onclick='$("#read").hide();$("#unread").show();$(".unreadChild").show();$(".readChild").hide();'>Show read</div>
<div onclick='$("#unread").hide();$("#read").show();$(".unreadChild").hide();$(".readChild").show();'>Show unread</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code:

```
<div id='articles'>
 <div id='read'>Read articles</div>   
  <div>Read1</div>
  <div>Read2</div>
 <div id='unread'>Unread articles </div>
  <div>Unread1</div>
  <div>Unread2</div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
 $("#showread").click(function() {
  $("#unread").hide();
  $("#unread").nextAll().hide();
  $("#read").show();
  $("#read").nextUntil("#unread").show();
});

$("#showunread").click(function() {
 $("#read").hide();
 $("#unread").prevUntil("#read").hide();
 $("#unread").show();
 $("#unread").nextAll().show();  
});
```